# How to add an outline to a Text Box in VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am creating a basic text box in excel using VBScript:

```
Dim TextBox
Set TextBox = objWorksheet.Shapes.AddTextBox(1, 57, 31.8, 228.24, 18.72)
TextBox.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Test"
TextBox.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
TextBox.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 14
TextBox.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name = "Arial"
TextBox.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

I want to add a black outline to this textbox. How do I accomplish this? I can't seem to find any documentation on the properties of textboxes and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help - I used the macro recorder to get this code, so a little bit of tidying needed

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 330.75, 76.5, 139.5 _
    , 125.25).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
End With
```

Comment: Weird, I try to do `TextBox.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0` and I get a runtime error saying that `TextBox` does not "support" a method or property called `ShapeRange`

Comment: Mine was made in MSOffice Professional Plus 2013. You may want to try recording your own macro to see how yours differs - I've not mucked around with graphics objects much before. Just start recording, insert a text box, right click on it and change the colour of the lines. Then stop recording and go to the macro environment, open up the code in the newest module and you should see how it's done

Comment: I was able to figure it out. For some reason VBScript doesn't recognize the ShapeRange method, so I removed it so it was just `TextBox.Line` From this I was able to edit the properties of the outline. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the macro recorder, I got this:

```
With TextBox.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
End With
```